# How to make the following format

Tags: lists, multicol, multicolumn

How to make this format???

[image]

I use the multicols in overleaf, code is below.

```
\begin{multicols}{2}
\footnotesize
\begin{itemize}
\setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\parsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
\item zero operation
\item skip connection
\item 3x3 max pooling
\item 3x3 conv
\item 3x3 conv, repeat 2
\item 3x3 separable conv
\item 3x3 separable conv, repeat 2
\item 3x3 dilated separable conv, dilation=2
\item 3x3 dilated separable conv, dilation=4
\item 3x3 dilated separable conv, dilation=2, repeat 2
\end{itemize}
\end{multicols}
```

But only got:

[image]

How to make the both two column and one column format?

Comment: Your top picture doesn't fit the code you display below (like there is no word "identity" in the code. Besides it is not a full working example that can be processed but just a snipped.  Your code asks for 2 columns for all items (balanced) and that is what the picture below produces. Are you asking that whenever an item is longer than a line it should become single column automatically? Or what?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This uses the `tabto` package, wrapped into a macro `\indentitem`, with a settable parameter `\myindent`.

As MadyYuvi notes, any line break in the right-hand bullets will not align with the right column, but reset to the left.  I did this because I had the impression that, in such cases, the OP would choose to set the item as a single line, in essence, only using the `itemize` split for short items.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabto,enumitem}
\newcommand\myindent{1.5in}
\newcommand\indentitem{\tabto{\myindent}$\bullet$\hspace{\labelsep}}
\begin{document}
\footnotesize
\begin{itemize}[itemsep=0pt, parsep=0pt]
\item zero operation 
\indentitem 3x3 separable conv, repeat 2 
\item skip connection 
\indentitem 3x3 max pooling 
\item 3x3 conv 
\indentitem 3x3 conv, repeat 2 
\item 3x3 separable conv 
\item 3x3 dilated separable conv, dilation=2 
\item 3x3 dilated separable conv, dilation=4 
\item 3x3 dilated separable conv, dilation=2, repeat 2 
\end{itemize} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry to point out that, if any turnover comes for the `\indentitem` then it will not align properly...

Comment: @MadyYuvi If, by "turnover", you mean line break, then you are correct...margin will reset to the left.  However, based on the OP's question, I gather that in such cases, he would set the item to the whole line.  I will edit to point this out, though.

Comment: Yes, I meant `linebreak` only...

Comment: Thanks for making a note on my point....

Answer (score 6):

With the help of `hlist` package, can meet the expectation:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{hlist}
\begin{document}


\hlist[label={\textbullet}]2
\hitem zero operation
\hitem skip connection
\hitem 3x3 max pooling
\hitem 3x3 conv
\hitem 3x3 conv, repeat 2
\hitem 3x3 separable conv
\hitem 3x3 separable conv, repeat 2
\hitem(2) 3x3 dilated separable conv, dilation=2
\hitem(2) 3x3 dilated separable conv, dilation=4
\hitem(2) 3x3 dilated separable conv, dilation=2, repeat 2
\endhlist


\end{document}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Two other solutions: with the `tasks` package, and another the `shortlst` package. The latter is not part of any distribution, for licensing reasons. Based on it, I defined a `tabitemize` environment, using two keys: `nc` for the number of columns 'defaults to 3), and  `il` for the interlining (defaults to 1.5).

For longer items, that must spread through columns, you can use `\task*` in the place of `\task` with the first package. Spreading is automatic with the second package.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage{shortlst, xkeyval, setspace}

\settasks{before-skip =\smallskipamount}

\makeatletter
\newcounter{ncol}
\define@key{lex}{nc}[3]{\setcounter{ncol}{#1}}%% 3 columns by default
\define@key{lex}{il}[1.5]{\def\@intln{#1}}% interlining![1]
\newenvironment{tabitemize}[1][]{%
\setkeys{lex}{nc,il,#1}
\settowidth{\labelwidth}{\mbox{\textbullet)}}
\setlength{\leftmargini}{2em}%\setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\shortitemwidth}{\dimexpr\linewidth/\value{ncol}-\labelwidth-2\labelsep\relax}%
\setstretch{\@intln}
\begin{shortitemize}}%
{\end{shortitemize}
 }%

\begin{document}

\begin{tasks}[style=itemize, after-item-skip=-1ex](2)
\task zero operation
\task skip connection
\task $3×3$ max pooling
\task $3×3$ conv
\task $3×3$ conv, repeat 2
\task $3×3$ separable conv
\task* $3×3$ separable conv, repeat 2
\task* $3×3$ dilated separable conv, dilation=2
\task* $3×3$ dilated separable conv, dilation=4
\task* $3×3$ dilated separable conv, dilation=2, repeat 2
    \end{tasks}

\vspace{1cm}
  \begin{tabitemize}[nc=2, il=1]
\item zero operation
\item skip connection
\item $3×3$ max pooling
\item $3×3$ conv
\item $3×3$ conv, repeat 2
\item $3×3$ separable conv
\item $3×3$ separable conv, repeat 2
\item $3×3$ dilated separable conv, dilation=2
\item $3×3$ dilated separable conv, dilation=4
\item $3×3$ dilated separable conv, dilation=2, repeat 2
\end{tabitemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: One of a nice suggestion...Hats off...